# DVD blank after burn

Tags: dvd, burning, dvd-burning

Here is my situation: I burn a DVD using the Live File System (which allows it to act like a flash drive). Burns without problem. Then I close the session, and all the files are still on the DVD. Then I eject the DVD and reinsert it, and it appears blank. If I now restart the computer, or hibernate - then the files reappear (not logoff - looks like it needs power off).

Any help so I can read my files after burning, or write more files without switching off the computer would be much appreciated.

Comment: What operating system and what program are you using? Maybe you need to umount the dvd before ejecting?

Comment: @ott-- Windows 7. Using Explorer. Before ejecting I right click the drive and click Close Session.

Comment: It works for me, just wrote some data to a DVD-RW. Ejecting takes some time, it said "prepare to eject" (in german). After inserting it again, the title and files appeared again. Did you eject with the button or from right-click menu?

Comment: @ott-- with the menu